# cmake and parallel building with "make -jN"

Tags: makefile, build, cmake, parallel-builds

I'm trying to setup a parallel CMake-based build for my source tree, but when I issue

```
$ cmake .
$ make -j2
```

I get:

```
jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule
```

as a warning. Does anyone have an idea if it is possible to fix it somehow?

Answer (score 25):

In the generated Makefile, when calling into a sub-make it needs to either use $(MAKE) (not just 'make') or else precede the line with a +.  That is, a rule should look like this:

```
mysubdir:
    $(MAKE) -C mysubdir
```

or like this:

```
mysubdir:
    +make -C mysubdir
```

If you don't do it one of those two ways, make will give you that warning.

I don't know anything about cmake, so maybe it's generating Makefiles that aren't correct.  Or maybe you did something incorrectly on your end.

Comment: I get said error even though I use `$(MAKE) -C mysubdir`. What's wrong here?

Comment: @apenwarr, can you make this into a separate question-and-answer pair? Your answer is not getting the attention it needs IMHO because the OP was concerned about CMake.

Answer (score 9):

In my case (with CMake 3.5.2) the trivial `cd build && cmake .. && make -j5` works just fine.

But, I do get the *jobserver unavailable* error when building custom targets (as dependencies of other targets) via the `cmake --build . --target foo` idiom.

Like this:

```
add_custom_target(buildroot
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install
   COMMENT "Populating buildroot..."
)
add_dependencies(deb buildroot)
add_dependencies(rpm buildroot) #... etc
```

— so that the user can `make deb` and it Just Works. CMake will regenerate makefiles if needed, run the compilation, `install` everything exactly as with `make install`, and then run my custom scripts to package up the populated buildroot into whatever shape or form I need.

Sure enough, I'd like to `make -j15 deb` — but that fails.

---

Now, as [explained](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2015-May/025293.html) on the mailing list by CMake devs, the root cause lies, surprisingly (or not), within GNU Make; there is a workaround.

The root cause is that **`make` will not pass its jobserver environment to child processes it thinks aren't `make`.**

To illustrate, here's a process tree (`ps -A f`) branch:

`…
\_ bash
   \_ make -j15 deb
      \_ make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 deb
         \_ make -f CMakeFiles/buildroot.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/buildroot.dir/build
            \_ /usr/bin/cmake --build . --target install   ⦿
               \_ /usr/bin/gmake install
                  …`

At ⦿ point, `make` drops jobserver environment, ultimately causing single-threaded compilation.

---

The **workaround** which worked great for me, as given away in the linked email, is to prefix all custom commands with **`+env`**. Like this:

```
add_custom_target(buildroot
   #-- this ↓↓↓ here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41268443/531179
   COMMAND +env ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install
   COMMENT "Populating buildroot..."
)
add_dependencies(deb buildroot)
add_dependencies(rpm buildroot) #... etc
```

In the end, this appears in the rule for `buildroot` in the appropriate makefile (CMake generates a bunch of them), and causes GNU Make to behave properly and respect `-j`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great except on Windows, where the syntax confuses make and causes the command to fail with the error "'+env' is not recognized as an internal or external command."

Comment: I'd say... too many softwares work great "except on Windows".

Comment: doing just `+` (without calling `env`) seems to work as well for my use case (e.g. `COMMAND +${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .. blah blah`), which avoids needing to use `env`.

Comment: What is needed is to have that '+' in front of the generated Makefile rule. On windows the generator used isn't the Makefiles generator, so the + doesn't end up in a Makefile and gets interpreted the way we want. Moreover in some case cmake doesn't put the string that follows COMMAND literally in the Makefile as a rule, but instead does for example: `cd working/directory && +env ...` which then obviously fails as well. What is REALLY needed is a way to tell cmake to add this '+' at the *beginning* of the makefile rule, iff the generator is a Makefiles generator with job-server support.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@Carlo Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487069/carlo-wood) in his comment [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41268443/547270), trying to convince `cmake` to add `+` to the *beginning* of the command in the cmake-generated makefile is not possible.

A work-around I found is to shield underlying make command from the make flags coming from cmake. This can be done by setting environment variable `MAKEFLAGS` to empty string for the custom command:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env
        MAKEFLAGS=
        make <your target and make options>
```

Hope this helps.